# Incorrect use of Parent Data Widget in ListView

Tags: android, flutter, api, dart, material-design

There are three tags in a row, which are fetching data from an API, now when the text coming from data is large, the pixels are overflowing , so i want that, when the data comes for first tag, it takes a a small space and then goes to the 2nd line, and other tags should remain at the same place, how can i do that.

below are the three tags named CustonTag which are children of a row and row is a child of a col, and col is a child of an expanded container

```
ListView(
          children: [
            HeadlineofArticle(article: article),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        CustomTag(background: Colors.black, children: [
                          CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 10,
                            backgroundImage:
                                NetworkImage(article.urlToImage.toString()),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 10),
                          Text(
                            article.author.toString(),
                            maxLines: 1,
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .bodyMedium!
                                .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                          )
                        ]),
                        CustomTag(background: Colors.grey.shade200, children: [
                          const Icon(
                            Icons.timer,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 10),
                          Text(
                            "TIME",
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .bodyMedium!
                                .copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                          )
                        ]),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        CustomTag(
                          background: Colors.grey.shade200,
                          children: [
                            const Icon(
                              Icons.remove_red_eye,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              " VIEW ",
                              style: Theme.of(context)
                                  .textTheme
                                  .bodyMedium!
                                  .copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
```

I tried expanding the different children but it was making it more wrong, i am expecting that they should be at their place and if the text is large than then text should come on the sec line/

Answer (score 1):

> Incorrect use of Parent Data Widget in ListView  is caused when you use `Expanded`  but not in `Row`,`Column` or `Flex`

```
ListView(
  children: [
    HeadlineofArticle(article: article),
    Expanded(   <<< this is your error
```

**An Expanded widget must be a descendant of a Row, Column, or Flex.**

read here for detail: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Solution: remove `Expanded`